# How to easily load dynamic .csv files to mySQL each month

Tags: mysql

Each month I load new data to MySQL Database. Columns 'Event', Event Description' and 'Location' are standard columns. The Columns which hold the data for the months are dynamic. That is this month I am reading a file which has months 2019M01, 2019M02 and 2019M03. Next month I will read 2019M02, 2019M03, 2019M04.

Is there any way to easily prepare tables that can read these dynamic .csv files that can take into account the dynamic nature of these data columns ?

Currently for each month I create new tables and then as we move to the next month I drop the previous table and create a new one which has the correct column names for the new month.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
/*We are in Month January*/;

    CREATE TABLE ex_1 (
      `Event` TEXT,
      `Event Description` TEXT,
      `Location` TINYTEXT,  
      `2019M01` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL, `2019M02` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL, `2019M03` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL
    );

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/BPerei23/Desktop/WORK/Projects/MAPE/MI-STAT/MarketIntelligence_DS-Spine_20190124.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE ex_1
    CHARACTER SET Latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE
SELECT * FROM ex_1;

/*We are now in Month February*/;

DROP TABLE ex_1;

    CREATE TABLE ex_2 (
      `Event` TEXT,
      `Event Description` TEXT,
      `Location` TINYTEXT,  
      `2019M02` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL, `2019M03` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL, `2019M04` DECIMAL (15,10) NOT NULL
    );

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/BPerei23/Desktop/WORK/Projects/MAPE/MI-STAT/MarketIntelligence_DS-Spine_20190224.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE ex_2
    CHARACTER SET Latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE
SELECT * FROM ex_2;
```

Comment: Sorry not an answer, but if your column names are linked to months / dates then there is something wrong with your model? Anyway, maybe look at crontab if it's available to you - schedule regular tasks

Comment: @matthewpage Why do you say there is something wrong with the model ? In the .csv raw data file the data columns are indeed months e..g 2019M01. To bring it MySQL Database I read this column name exactly as is in the .csv file and hence create the table with the same column name.

Comment: You can map the csv fields to any column, they don't need to match in name. But if it works, don't fiddle ...